# Remove elements on checkbox tick which adds other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to build some validation functionality for checkboxes which includes ticking all 6 as green when all are at yes, yellow if not checked and x if no is selected.

It seems to work fine except from removing the previous colours once I've added them. I tried .remove from the different images when the other is selected but not having much luck when I tried that.

I pretty much need a way to look at whenever an i class is loaded, it removes any other tags

It's meant to work that is has exclamation when something is not ticked, X when No and on all 6, tick green.

FIDDLE: 
https://jsfiddle.net/3c1vhkwf/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />');

      $('.chkValidation input').change(function() {

        $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);

        if(checkValues())
        {
          if($('.chkValidation :checked').size() == 6)
          {
            $('<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="color:green; display:inline-block;"></i>').insertAfter('.chkValidation :checked');
          }
          else
          {
            $('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:orange"></i>').insertAfter(this);
          }
        }
        else
        {
          $('<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" style="color:red"></i>').insertAfter(this);
        }

      });

      function checkValues(){
        var valid = true;
        $('.chkValidation input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {   
         if($(this).prop('checked'))
         {
            if($(this).prop('value') == "No")
            {
                valid = false;
            }
         }
        })
        return valid;
      }
    });
```

Comment: I don't use jQuery but you appear to be adding a new element with each change event. You should be just adding/removing a class from the element on change. [MDN classList API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make classes which can be attached somewhere onto the elements that need to be validated:

```
.error:after {
  content: '\f00d';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

Because you only want to have the checks if all are checked, it is hard to return them to a previous state if, for example, an additional box is checked.  I decided to just make the fieldset itself green, but you can do many different things. For these checks, you need to check if the same number of `Yes` checkboxes matches the number of them checked:

```
$('.chkValidation').find('input[value=Yes]:checked').length === $('.chkValidation').find('input[value=Yes]').length`
```

As well as if there are none with `No` checked:

```
$('.chkValidation').find('input[value=No]:checked').length === 0)
```

Finally, to figure out if a set isn't checked, find the `closest` input (checkbox) and see if it is also checked:

```
var yes = $this.closest('fieldset').find('input[value=Yes]').prop('checked');
var no = $this.closest('fieldset').find('input[value=No]').prop('checked');
if (no)
  $fieldset.addClass('error');
if (!yes && !no)
  $fieldset.addClass('warn');
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3c1vhkwf/8/)

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned in the other comment this is from a piece of software that has a forms component, not much luck when it comes to adding custom classes otherwise it'd be a walk in the park! That looks like it works great, I'll see if there's anyway I can plug that in somehow.

Comment: Oh I see.  So what exactly do you have control over? I see you are inserting bootstrap css, so why can't you insert your own? You are free to add classes to the elements with jQuery without the access to the HTML.

Comment: Just about managed it I think. Your reply is definitely correct and the issue is on my end now so marked as answer.

Comment: I appreciate it, but don't mark it as an answer if it doesn't help you! You are free to wait for other responses.

Comment: After a coffee I figured out a way to add what I need. Thanks very much! I think the number of people who would have worked on this software with forms  functionality might be barely in double digits so I'd be waiting a while. Thankfully your code did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into your fiddle but the html is all jumbled up. Anyway from what i can see I believe you can do something like this, lets say if all the checkbox are ticked Yes, you hide the exclamation icon by targeting their class:

```
if($('.chkValidation :checked').size() == 6){
  $(".fa-exclamation-circle").hide(); //hides all exclamation icons
```

Comment: It's from Laserfiche forms, unfortunately there isn't much hope of getting rid of the spaghetti. I'll give it a shot!